# Integrated dash-app (using django_plotly_dash) does not get enough space

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I am integrating a dash-app into django for the first time. I use `django_plotly_dash` for this.

I think I am doing it the standard way:

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('trial',views.trial,name='trial'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import my_first_dash_plotly_app.simple_dash_app
def trial(request):
    return render(request, 'my_first_dash_plotly_app/trial.html')
```

`simple_dash_app.py`

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample1')


# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")


app.layout = html.Div(style={}, children=[


    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-2',
        figure=fig
    )
])
```

`trial.html`

```
{%load plotly_dash%}

{%plotly_app name="SimpleExample1"%}
```

This is just the standard-example from the plotly/dash-introduction.

It works somehow but looks really ugly. You have to scroll to see the plot completely.
[image: cut off plot where you to scroll to see it completely]
If I remember correctly I have seen this behaviour before outside of the django-world.

Is there an easy fix? Should I file a bug-report on that or is it just me doing something completely wrong? I think this behaviour should not be default: The default should be that each graph gets the size it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding `ratio=1` into the `plotly_app` tag. In your case this would be:

```
{% plotly_app name="SimpleExample1" ratio=1 %}
```

The problem is that the child `div` of the tag has a height of 0. The `ratio=1` fixes this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know why I even see anything even though the `height` of the `div` is equal to zero? Is it because the `padding-botton` is equal to 10% (at least in default) and you see the plot in the padding-area (not the content-area)? Naivly one would assume that if the `height` of the `div` is zero there should be nothing to see...
I am new to html, maybe you know a nice ressource that explains it?